# Exporting data in access to text file with a dot separator

Tags: database, export, specifications

I am using Access 2007 and I wish to be able to export my data to a text file while having the export specifications to allow me to use a '.' instead of a comma or the other default characters given to me. Is this possible?

Comment: See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255004/exporting-data-into-a-performatted-file

Answer (score 0):

here's one way of doing it:

1. select the table/query you want to export on the navigation pane
2. right-click your table/query and select "Export" > "Text File" (or click the "Text File" button on the "Export" section of the "External Data" tab of the ribbon.
3. choose a location to save the text file and click the "OK" button
4. on the next screen of the wizard dialog box, select "Delimited" and click the "Next" button
5. choose "Other" as your delimiter and type a dot into the box next to it
6. choose a text qualifier from the dropdown if you want text fields to be quoted in your output
7. check the "Include Field Names on First Row" box if you like
8. click the "Advanced" button for more options
9. change the "Decimal Symbol" option to something other than a dot.  (this is necessary because your output field delimiter cannot match your decimal symbol or else the export operation will fail.)
10. click the "OK" button
11. click the "Finish" button

that should handle it.  i'm assuming that there are no decimal numbers or dots in any of your text fields, or else you'll have problems parsing the output...