# Exporting data into a pre-formatted file

Tags: ms-access, text, export

I am using Access 2007 and I wish to export my data into a text file with a '.' separator. I don't seem to have any luck finding an answer so I wondering if it were possible to have a pre-formatted text or CSV file that it would export my data into so I could have my '.' separators.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Exporting data in access to text file with a dot seperator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254467/exporting-data-in-access-to-text-file-with-a-dot-seperator)

Comment: Giovanni You might like to delete http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13254467/exporting-data-in-access-to-text-file-with-a-dot-seperator as it has no answers.

Answer (score 1):

Right click ---> Export ----> Text File   ----> pick location (don't check export data with frmatting and layout ----> OK ----> delimited, ok ---> next----->  other "."

Comment: Note, however, that this will have to be in a locale that does not use a stop as the decimal separator, or else choose Advanced and change the decimal separator.

Answer (score 1):

Working with a schema.ini file

In MS Access

```
 Sub TransferData()
    'Assuming file exits
    Kill "z:\docs\export.txt"
    CurrentDb.Execute "select * into [text;database=z:\docs\].[export.txt] from table1"
 End Sub
```

The Schema.ini file, which must be in the directory that is used for the export:

```
[export.txt]
Format=Delimited(.)
DecimalSymbol=,
```

More information: [Schema.ini](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms709353%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

here's one way of doing it (reposted from my original answer to the duplicated question):

1. select the table/query you want to export on the navigation pane
2. right-click your table/query and select "Export" > "Text File" (or
   click the "Text File" button on the "Export" section of the
   "External Data" tab of the ribbon.
3. choose a location to save the text file and click the "OK" button
4. on the next screen of the wizard dialog box, select "Delimited" and
   click the "Next" button
5. choose "Other" as your delimiter and type a dot into the box next to
   it
6. choose a text qualifier from the dropdown if you want text fields to
   be quoted in your output
7. check the "Include Field Names on First Row" box if you like
8. click the "Advanced" button for more options
9. change the "Decimal Symbol" option to something other than a dot.
   (this is necessary because your output field delimiter cannot match
   your decimal symbol or else the export operation will fail.)
10. click the "OK" button
11. click the "Finish" button

that should handle it. i'm assuming that there are no decimal numbers or dots in any of your text fields, or else you'll have problems parsing the output...