# Export Access query results to csv

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an access database which manipulates data from a Magento e-commerce store, reformats the data and (hopefully!) spits out a CSV file which can then be imported into ebay Turbolister for mass upload to eBay.

I have got as far as creating a query which correctly lays out the data into the format required by Turbolister.

My issues are various (including some which appear to be related to Access' handling of large field contents), however the crux of my problem is that I am struggling to get working a simple script which exports the query results as a properly formatted CSV (including doubling up on double quotes where required inside a text value i.e. if the value itself contains quotes which need to be retained).

The DoCmd.TransferText solution throws an error related to field size ('the field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add') so thats no good.

Has anyone got a good working CSV export routine in VBA that they can suggest?

Cheers

Comment: Have you looked at using schema.ini ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13255004/exporting-data-into-a-preformatted-file/13255522#13255522 ) ?

Comment: Do not forget that you can use replace with queries -- `replace(myfield,"""","""""")` -- you can use this with any text exports fields in the query to export.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an old function I sometimes used to use, it allows you to specify the delimeter, it also checks the data it's outputting and if it can't be evaluated to either a date or a numeric etc, then it uses double quotes:

```
Public Function ExportTextDelimited(strQueryName As String, strDelimiter As String)

Dim rs          As Recordset
Dim strHead     As String
Dim strData     As String
Dim inti        As Integer
Dim intFile     As Integer
Dim fso         As New FileSystemObject

On Error GoTo Handle_Err

    fso.CreateTextFile ("C:\Untitled.csv")

    Set rs = Currentdb.OpenRecordset(strQueryName)

    rs.MoveFirst

    intFile = FreeFile
    strHead = ""

    'Add the Headers
    For inti = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
        If strHead = "" Then
            strHead = rs.Fields(inti).Name
        Else
            strHead = strHead & strDelimiter & rs.Fields(inti).Name
        End If
    Next

    Open "C:\Untitled.csv" For Output As #intFile

    Print #intFile, strHead

    strHead = ""

    'Add the Data
    While Not rs.EOF

        For inti = 0 To rs.Fields.Count - 1
            If strData = "" Then
                strData = IIf(IsNumeric(rs.Fields(inti).value), rs.Fields(inti).value, IIf(IsDate(rs.Fields(inti).value), rs.Fields(inti).value, """" & rs.Fields(inti).value & """"))
            Else
                strData = strData & strDelimiter & IIf(IsNumeric(rs.Fields(inti).value), rs.Fields(inti).value, IIf(IsDate(rs.Fields(inti).value), rs.Fields(inti).value, """" & rs.Fields(inti).value & """"))
            End If
        Next

        Print #intFile, strData

        strData = ""

        rs.MoveNext
    Wend

        Close #intFile

rs.Close
Set rs = Nothing

'Open the file for viewing
Application.FollowHyperlink "C:\Untitled.csv"   

Exit Function

Handle_Err:
MsgBox Err & " - " & Err.Description

End Function
```

It may need a couple of tweaks as I've taken out some bits which were only relevant to my particular case but this may be a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for this. Even this is struggling to handle text fields with both commas and quotes already present in them, but will see if I can tweak it a little. Will let you know how I get on.

Comment: @cheshirepine Sorry I missed that bit, your data should never contain the delimeter you are planning to use as this will complicate things, generally why csv is not the best format : (

Comment: Yeah I realise that, but when your data contains HTML with class tags enclosed in Quotes, and CSV is the only option available to you to import into Turbolister, your options are kind of limited! :D Am working around them one by one tho.

Comment: @cheshirepine And I'm guessing to complicate matters more, you don't have any other data options available from your e-commerce store?

Comment: Am already looking at an XML export, but that doesnt really help with the import into Turbolister, which ONLY accepts CSV in a predetermined structure. the XML export is neater but I am still left with the same issues on transfer to TL.... :(

Comment: OK, got it working, but I am seeing corruption in some of the large text fields. Do I need to specify encoding anywhere and if so, where and how?

Comment: @cheshirepine Are you referring to XML or the original format?  I think XML would be a good way to go, VB supports XML and should be fairly simple to load into a table, then you can run the CSV export.

Comment: With a small amount of additional work on the code provided by @Matt above I now have a fully working export routine, which imports perfectly happily into TurboLister. Thanks all for your help.